# Concatenate variable with a fact in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use a variable and the results of a previous task as input. Here is my code.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    v_hostname: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    v_datacentre: DC-UK-LON-GS
    v_username: YYYYYYYY
    v_password: XXXXXXXX
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Find the folder for the VM
    vmware_guest_find:
      hostname: "{{ v_hostname }}"
      datacenter: "{{ v_datacentre }}"
      username: "{{ v_username }}"
      password: "{{ v_password }}"
      validate_certs: no
      name: MYVMNAME
    register: folder

   - debug:
       msg:
         - "{{ folder.folders }}"

   - name: Gather facts from VM
     connection: local
     gather_facts: false
     vmware_guest_facts:
       hostname: "{{ v_hostname }}"
       datacenter: "{{ v_datacentre }}"
       username: "{{ v_username }}"
       password: "{{ v_password }}"
       validate_certs: no
       folder: "{{ v_datacentre }}{{ folder.folders }}"
       name: MYVMNAME
```

The last line tries to use the defined variable v_datacentre and append the value from the registered fact from the previous task. However the concatenation produces some unwanted wrapping chars:

```
ansible-playbook 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/export/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed /export/home/ansible/inventory_prod inventory source with ini plugin
 [WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: gather_facts

PLAYBOOK: mainvm.yml *****************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in mainvm.yml

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [TEST1] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /export/home/ansible/mainvm.yml:12
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest_find.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401="` echo /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpM_Pf2B TO /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401/vmware_guest_find.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401/ /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401/vmware_guest_find.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401/vmware_guest_find.py; rm -rf "/export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621823.18-119950066241401/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "folders": [
        "/vm/LON-GS-AD/LON-GS-AD-UNIX"
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "datacenter": "DC-UK-LON-GS",
            "hostname": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "MYVMNAME",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "username": "XXXXXXXX",
            "uuid": null,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    }
}

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /export/home/ansible/mainvm.yml:23
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "/vm/LON-GS-AD/LON-GS-AD-UNIX"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Gather facts from standalone ESXi server] **************************************************************************************************************
task path: /export/home/ansible/mainvm.yml:28
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest_facts.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166="` echo /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmp43NXf_ TO /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166/vmware_guest_facts.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166/ /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166/vmware_guest_facts.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166/vmware_guest_facts.py; rm -rf "/export/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523621827.79-78942665802166/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "datacenter": "XXXXXX",
            "folder": "DC-UK-LON-GS[u'/vm/LON-GS-AD/LON-GS-AD-UNIX']",
            "hostname": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "MYVMNAME",
            "name_match": "first",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "username": "XXXXXXXX",
            "uuid": null,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Unable to gather facts for non-existing VM MYVMNAME"
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/export/home/ansible/mainvm.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

The results of folder.folders is correctly printed by debug but in the last step the concatenation gives:

```
"folder": "DC-UK-LON-GS[u'/vm/LON-GS-AD/LON-GS-AD-UNIX']",
```

I confess to being a bit of an Ansible newbie but I don't understand where the [u' and ] come from. I just want to use the combined strings as input. Can anyone please explain or show solution or point me at some beginners documents for this sort of variable use?

Thanks.

Comment: `folders` is a list!

Answer (score 1):

So after some further playing turns out that the vmware_guest_find returns a list (and it's in the docs!!!) so I need to either pick the 1st item if there will only be one group or loop though them.

```
folder: "{{ v_datacentre }}{{ folder.folders[0] }}"
```

This does the job.